# Python преобразование звукового сигнала в массив чисел

Tags: python, массивы, аудио, signal

Задача такая:
Идет проигрывание файла 'audio.mp3'
Необходимо выходной сигнал представить как массив чисел[10, 32, 43, 54, 65, 76, 87, 98, 32, 31]
Этот массив будет передаваться в соответствующую функцию каждые 0.1 сек.

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, но гляньте http://datareview.info/article/vizualiziruem-svoyu-muzykalnuyu-kollekciyu/ может чем поможет.

Comment: Думаю, мне это поможет. Благодарю

Comment: Можно закрывать тему.. Я сделал другое решение..